# How can I programmatically upload values (web client) and get the result in a scenario such as the following?

Tags: php, vb.net

How would I be able to use a webclient to fill a form such as this one ?
http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Simple forms seems to work but this one I can't get right.
Is there a way to trigger the php jobs called in that page from the web client ? Here is the code I would use normally.

```
Private Sub SubmitData(Data As String)
    Const URL As String = "http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/"
    Dim Values As New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
    Values.Add("html", Data)
    Dim WebClient As New WebClient

    Try
        Dim ResponseBytes As Byte() = WebClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", Values)
        Dim Output As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ResponseBytes)
        Console.WriteLine(Output)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Failure", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning)
    End Try
End Sub
```

So, if I have an input like this one

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         A Small Hello 
      </TITLE>
   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <H1>Hi</H1>
   <P>This is very minimal "hello world" HTML document.</P> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I end up with an output like this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE> A Small Hello </TITLE> </HEAD><BODY> <H1>Hi</H1> <P>This is very minimal "hello world" HTML document.</P> </BODY></HTML>
```

The interessing part in the page source code
[image: webpage form source]

Therefore, I am uploading value in the vb.net with "html" as name and the content I want to send as value.

Using Fiddler, I can see the following: When using a visual interface (web browser), the jobs.php script is called and update the page with the desired output.

However, when using the webclient, the jobs.php script is never triggered. 
Below, Fiddler view
[image: Fiddler]

Can I trigger the job myself programmatically and if yes, How would I accomplish this and get the result back.

Another interessing fact to note is the use of the iFr variable in the page script. Can I manually ensure this is set to false ?

By the way, I am perfectly aware there are libraries to minify code without relying on a web page that could change or disappears without notice. I am more interested in the programmatical interaction between .net and the web. 
The solution (or clues) could involve any other control than the webclient.

Comment: This is confusing.  The source code that you are showing does not hit the `jobs.php` endpoint as a result of the form submission.  That's just something that is executed on page load.  Is there more in the source page that shows what really happens when the form is submitted?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the "form action="/minifyer/" which post the form to itself and perform the action at reload ? 

The page source is the one at the url mentionned in my post http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/ and it is not much longer than what I did post.